# How did this address steal my Ethereum ERC-20 Tokens?

Tags: erc-20, security

A person on Twitter told me about this DApp that gives her 1% ROI each day and since I was new to crypto and her lies was really believable to me and I had really big FOMO. I first put 100 USDT into Trust Wallet, then after I see the 1% ROI per day I put 600 USDT more cause since I still see the funds in my Trust Wallet I assumed it was safe.But after a few sentences of what she say and have time to read more about the DApp I didn't want to continue the Smart Contract anymore but when I revoke the Smart Contract it emptied my wallet and sent the money to this address?

https://etherscan.io/address/0x88dea47a091bd642464d34c70ffb347c89f3d371#tokentxns

I don't know what's the point on revoking Smart Contract if the hacker can just code an auto empty before the removal is executed and weirdest thing is the scammer doesn't even use the funds. I spam clicked revoke Smart Contract 3 times on Wallet Connect because it didn't register.

Here are the notifications from my phone https://i.stack.imgur.com/75eip.jpg. So sometimes I scroll it show that 716 USDT was sent with Smart Contract executed and sometimes it just show Smart Contract executed 3 times? I didn't know that accepting the Smart Contract means the website can spend unlimited amount of my money. Here was the malicious DApp I was using:

**Phishing site** --> https: //veriteus.com/ ?code=0006

(even say partners with popular companies and a lot of participants. I never give my secret phrase/private key away to anyone or download anything so I don't think my PC could be affected by malware because I just accepted the malicious Smart Contract that didn't tell me anything about what permissions it gives. Any one know if I should Full Scan my PC with Bitdefender or switch devices in case?

P.S

All I get to approve was this https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwqVK.jpg which did not say access to my tokens or how many tokens I'm approving for access at all. I was thinking if I can even start a lawsuit againsn't this DApp for not allowing me to know what I'm approving and that's all it say.

Comment: Hmm, your case is really interesting. I want to learn more from your unfortunate experience and figure out what happened. Would you maybe be interested in arranging an online meeting?

Comment: I would like to know what happend and if I could get my money back would be great because I'm a student so I don't get a full time salary and if I had that money I could of leverage bitcoin to 18.3k and rebuy it a while ago so I basically lost more than 700 usdt.

Comment: I went through a similar situation, where j was going to do a withdrawl and my wallet was drained I was using trust wallet and they took 1,100 from that wallet and another 1,000 from my Defi wallet..**strong text**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum. What to do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-or-suspect-scam-on-ethereum-what-to-do)

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the DAPP you posted, and its a **Phishing site.**

[image]

Really nasty, I disabled the link in your question to protect the safety of other users.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i've seen lots o scam contracts and websites these days but most of them send approve for access your tokens to you, and usually you sign this message without check what you approving, even how many token approving??

Basically you give allowance for your tokens to Scammer, and they can transfer this amount that you approved in a sign message, they try to convince you to spend more tokens and if you approve more tokens for them , they still waiting and do not transfer, after you revoke. they realize that you want to get back your tokens.
In this time they can transfer as much as amount which you signed in a approve message.

Comment: All I get to approve was this https://imgur.com/a/suySR1j which did not say access to my tokens or how many tokens I'm approving for access at all. Is it illegal to not tell me anything and can I start a lawsuit on the DApp since it didn't allow me to know what I'm approving?

Comment: Actually when you signing an approve message , message show you simple detail, for example if i want to get approve form you to access your USDC tokens, in a sign message this message appear for you:
"Give permission to access your USDC?
By granting permission, you are allowing the following contract to access your funds" If you click on "EDIT PERMISSION you will see you giving access how many tokens by this sign, the problem is most of users do not check how much amount approved by this message and also they don't know you can lose your tokens with just signing an approve message.

Comment: But it didn't give me anything to sign the only thing I get to approve was the picture I sent. It did not say allow me to give access to all USDT in my wallet.

Answer (score 0):

This happen to me the same through dapp site https://ens-defierc20.org ) I connected from my trust wallet claiming liquidity pool in USDT With high return . When u connect does not mention any thing later discovered that Im connected to a snart contract . I lost all my 500000 + USDT . Im strugling to recover my USDT